# STM32F072 - Working with HAL and FatFS

Tags: microcontroller, spi, sd, stm32f0, hal-library

I am trying to make small data logger project with STM32F072 as an opportunity to get more familiar with STM's HAL.

With CubeMX I generated HAL code that has SPI and also includes FatFS.

Right now I am having issue gluing SPI low level drivers to FatFS.

Can someone please point me in the right direction or post some examples on how to glue HAL SPI functions to FatFS? Right now I see that there is following declaration generated by HAL, but I can't seem to find any actual implementation that works.

```
Diskio_drvTypeDef  USER_Driver =
{
  USER_initialize,
  USER_status,
  USER_read, 
#if  _USE_WRITE
  USER_write,
#endif  /* _USE_WRITE == 1 */  
#if  _USE_IOCTL == 1
  USER_ioctl,
#endif /* _USE_IOCTL == 1 */
};
```

Any examples or documentation on how to implement this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally manage to implement low-level drivers and they seem to work nicely.

I'm sharing [source code](https://gist.github.com/sasakaranovic/37eddf3f332108e728326c991d2081a8) of my implementation in case somebody else gets stuck at the same part that I was.

Comment: thanks for making your code accessible, it worked instantly.

Comment: @Calculon. Your solution could be really useful to me.... but the link does not work. Are you able to fix?

Comment: @TheGrovesy Sorry about that. My GitHub username got changed so the gist was no longer pointing to the correct account. I've fixed it so you should be good now. Let me know if you need any additional help.